# how to grant access to a sql authentication account to access linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

how to grant access to a sql authentication account to access linked server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should go through this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

The following example creates a linked server S1_instance1 on an instance of SQL Server by using the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider.

```
 EXEC sp_addlinkedserver      
 @server=N'S1_instance1',    
 @srvproduct=N'',   
 @provider=N'SQLNCLI',    
 @datasrc=N'S1\instance1';
```

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the security context you have set up in your linked server. If you have it set to...

- Use the current security context: you need to ensure that the sql authenticated account is created on BOTH servers with the same username and password
- Use a specific security context: you need to map the local sql authenticated account to the remote authenticated account on the linked server setup page

IMHO the first option is the simpliset method which we have used to good effect in the past but it does require you have admin permissions on both servers to set up the accounts